# Making a three phase squirrel cage induction motor in PLECS?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, software

I was just curious if I was to make a Three phase squirrel cage induction motor connected to a
mechanical load System Block Diagram in PLECS with a rated frequency of 60hz, 6 poles, 220V rated stator voltage and a Friction coefficient of 0.25. Would I just be using an asynchronous machine in place of the three phase motor?

Answer (score 0):

A Squirrel Cage Induction Motor (SCIM) is an asynchronous machine.  As in the frequency and poles determines synchronous speed and the SCIM rotates at a slightly slower speed to produce torque.

$$n_S = \frac {120 f}{p} =  \frac {120 \times 60Hz}{6} = 1,200 rpm$$

Synchronous speed is 1,200 rpm, but motor speed depends on load torque.

If the slip is 5%, motor speed would be 1,140rpm.  As slip and load vary, motor speed varies, so a SCIM is asynchronous.  If motor rotated at 1,200rpm (synchronous speed), there would be no torque.